# Custom Upload Directory does not change attachment meta

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make a download script for a password protected wordpress site. To make use of PHPs readfile() function I need to retrieve the full attachment URL based on it's ID i am passing to the download script.

I made a Custom Post Type named **Downloads** and also changed it's upload directory to a folder inside wp-content also named **downloads**.

Here is the code for it:

```
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'custom_upload_directory' );

function custom_upload_directory( $args ) {

   $id = $_REQUEST['post_id'];
   $parent = get_post( $id )->post_parent;

   if( "downloads" == get_post_type( $id ) || "downloads" == get_post_type( $parent ) ) {

      $args['path'] = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/downloads';
      $args['url']  = WP_CONTENT_URL . '/downloads';


   }
   return $args;
```

}

Upload works fine and when I click the link to the desired file, the ID is passed to a script via $_POST, which also works fine. But I just can't figure out a way to get the right file URL. Here's what I tried:

```
wp_get_attachment_url( $id );                       // returns: example.com/wp-content/uploads/html/theme/wp-content/downloads/filename.ext
wp_get_attachment_link( $id );                      // returns: <a href="example.com/wp-content/uploads/html/theme/wp-content/downloads/filename.ext">slug</a>
get_attachment_link( $id );                         // returns: example.com/downloads/file    (without .ext)
get_attached_file( $id, true );                     // returns: html/theme/wp-content/downloads/filename.ext
get_post_meta( $id, '_wp_attached_file', false );   // returns: html/theme/wp-content/downloads/filename.ext
wp_get_attachment_metadata( $id );                  // returns nothing
```

What I expected any of those functions to return was **example.com/wp-content/downloads/filename.ext**

But as you can see, some mix up the default upload directory and combine it with the new one while others just return half of the full URL (html/theme/... it's the directory the website sits on the server). So any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Your filter callback `custom_upload_directory` is also called during a function like `wp_get_attachment_url()`, because it uses `wp_upload_dir()` - but I assume that the REQUEST var is missing at that point, leading to unexpected results.

Comment: On my downloads page I link to my download script, passing the file's ID via Ajax/POST. So calling `wp_get_attachment_url( $id )` (and so on) has the right ID.

Comment: But doesn't it mean it will break everywhere else?

Comment: I checked the DB also. Inside `wp_posts` table the guid column stores the correct values e. g. http://example.com/wp-content/downloads/file.ext This leads me to the assumption, that the upload works well and uses the rewritten upload directory. However, if I try to get the URL via the functions noted above it does not work. In short: Yes, it definitely breaks somewhere. I am just not sure where. DB is right, upload is right, ID is right. But the return of those functions is not.

Comment: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.8/src/wp-includes/post.php#L5238 I just noticed that `wp_get_attachment_url()` actually _does_ have a fallback for using the gui, but it's not recommended (see code comment).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. However, if I had to choose I'd prefer another solution that's more... recommend ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hours, days and even weeks later I finally found an answer and modified it to fit my needs. I came as far as displaying the right URL (the modified one) inside the file upload lightbox of Wordpress. But after publishing/updating the post it went back to the same old `.../wp-content/uploads/file.ext` URL.

Someone else, [somewhere else](https://metabox.io/support/topic/how-to-set-a-upload-directory-for-file_upload/) got exactly the same problem and fortunately it is said there, that you must not just alter `$args['path']` and `$args['url']` but you also have to alter `basedir`, `baseurl` and `subdir`.

So, the complete code to change a custom post types upload directory (in this case I chose the directory .../wp-content/downloads) is the following:

```
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'change_upload_dir' );

function change_upload_dir( $args ) {

    $id = $_REQUEST['post_id'];

    if( get_post_type( $id ) == 'downloads' ) {

      $args['basedir'] = wp_normalize_path( WP_CONTENT_DIR . 'downloads' );
      $args['baseurl'] = content_url() . '/downloads';
      $args['path']    = $args['basedir'];
      $args['url']     = $args['baseurl'];
      $args['subdir']  = '';

      return $args;

    }

}
```

So now, `calling wp_get_attachment_url()` finally results in something like `example.com/wp-content/downloads/file.ext`